# What will be prioritized in a conflict between ~/.ssh/config hostname and /etc/hosts?

Tags: ssh, hostname, hosts

What if one host is defined in `/etc/hosts` like:

```
192.168.0.100   server
```

and one is defined in `~/.ssh/config` like:

```
 Host    server
         HostName    192.168.0.101
```

and you ssh into server: `ssh server`.

How would such a conflict be resolved? I guess one has higher priority than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `ssh server` the server part could be a real host name or some ssh internal "nickname". ssh first looks for some nickname in .ssh/config, if it finds a configuration there it will use this. If it does not find a configuration it assumes a real hostname and tries to resolve it via /etc/host and dns.

Answer (score 1):

The file `~/.ssh/config` has nothing to do with `/etc/hosts`. Rather it's a configuration file for `ssh` to use if it exists.

You can see that `ssh` refers to this file prior to doing anything else by using the verbose switch, `-v`, to `ssh`.

#### Host entry in ~/.ssh/config

Here I have an entry in my `~/.ssh/config`file for a server named "skinner". I'm enabling debug level 3 by including 3 `-v`'s switches.

*Example*

```
$ ssh -vvv skinner 
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/saml/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/saml/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/saml/.ssh/config line 35: Applying options for skinner
debug1: /home/saml/.ssh/config line 55: Applying options for *
debug3: cipher ok: arcfour [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: blowfish-cbc [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug3: ciphers ok: [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
...
```

In the above you can see that `ssh` is making use of this definition and not even consulting the system's name resolution facilities.

#### No host entry in ~/.ssh/config

If there is no corresponding entry in the `~/.ssh/config` file, then `ssh` will consult the system's DNS resolution to find out how to connect to a hostname that's been specified.

*Example*

```
$ ssh -vvv skinner
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/saml/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/saml/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/saml/.ssh/config line 55: Applying options for *
debug3: cipher ok: arcfour [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug3: cipher ok: blowfish-cbc [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug3: ciphers ok: [arcfour,blowfish-cbc]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/saml/.ssh/master-saml@skinner:22" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to skinner [192.168.1.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Here you can see that `ssh` is consulting the system to find out the IP address for the hostname "skinner".

**NOTE:** You can use `getent` to look up hostnames on your system:

```
$ getent hosts skinner
192.168.1.3     skinner.dom.net
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally, for Unix software in general, user-specific settings (in this case, `~/.ssh/config`) would override system-wide settings (in this case, `/etc/hosts`); thus, the settings in `~/.ssh/config` would be higher priority.